# Ruby on Rails: How can I get all sessions data from Redis on server side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, encryption, redis

I need to get all active sessions' data from my Rails application. I am using Redis for session store.

I tried `REDIS.keys` and then `REDIS.get("SESSION_KEY")`but it seems like **encrypted data**.

Is there any painless solution to get live sessions' data on Rails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Decrypt the Rails session data from Redis

Ruby on Rails using Marshal method for saving objects to cache.
For example:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/rack_cache.rb#L17

You can unmarshalling this data as follows:

```
Marshal.load(REDIS.get("SESSION_KEY"))
```

Comment: Thank you bro, you are my hero!

Comment: This doesn't work in Rails 7 anymore. Prefer using higher level function `Rails.cache.read` to decode the session from Redis